Access HP ILO using separate adapter. Is it possible?
I have an ILO on my hp server. Could I access ilo using separate ethernet adapter?

Is there a cable connected to the ILO?

Do you mean can you configure the ilo on a different network, and access the ilo from that other network? Yes, that is the preferred method. The ilo should be connected to a management network or VLAN that only specific devices have access to so you can manage the server out of band.

No, that's not possible. You need to use either the dedicated iLO NIC or the shared NIC in the server, as supported by the platform/server model.
Of course, you can access iLO from anywhere in your network, as configured.
